# Modular Arithmetic Question -- Sum of digits of consecutive numbers.

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

I'm having trouble understanding the following problem.

Take three consecutive integers with the largest being a multiple of three.
e.g. 61, 62, 63.

Find the sum of these numbers... 186.

Add these digits together... 1 + 8 + 6 = 15

Add these digits together... 1 + 5 = 6

No matter what consecutive numbers you start with, you always end with 6. How would I go about writing this as a proof.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know that if a number is $k $ more than a multiple of $9$ the the sum of its digits is also $k $ more than a multiple of $9$?  And the sum of *those* digits is $k $ more than a multiple of $9$? And you can repeat this indefinitely and you will *always* end up with $k $ more than a multiple of $9$?

Answer (score 2):

Let the largest be $3k$.

$$(3k-2)+(3k-1)+3k\equiv6(\mod 9)$$

Since there is only one digit left and the sum $(\mod 9)$ is an invariant, it must be $6$ in the end.